Why does networkx omit an edge?
Why this piece of code does not display the edge between the vertices 0 and 2?
I'm new to networkx and pytorch_geometric. Sorry if I'm asking a very simple question.
import networkx as nx
from torch_geometric.data import Data
edge_index = torch.tensor([[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0]], dtype=torch.long)
x = torch.eye(3, dtype=torch.float)
data = Data(x=x, edge_index=edge_index.t().contiguous())
g = torch_geometric.utils.to_networkx(data, to_undirected=True)
nx.draw(g)

The output is the following figure:

With the command nx.draw_circular(g), it gives the following figure, again omitting the mentioned edge.

are you sure [2,0] is not just under the connections [0,1] and [1,2]?

@KenzoStaelens You mentioned an interesting point. How can we see this edge?

@KenzoStaelens I tried nx.draw_circular(g) but again this edge is omitted.

have you tried with [0,2] yet(sorry can't test, the thing seems to not want to render here :/ ).... Edit: forgot plt.show() yes it seems to be the order of your vertex

(My last comment has been deleted!) It worked. But why?

i have no idea, i just assumed ordering lower to higher might've solved the problem so maybe something with math internally?
